# Bootstrap justified navbar not evenly spacing menu items on Internet explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap 3.1.1 and using the nav-justified class for my main navigation. It works well on all the major browsers except IE11 and below. Firefox, Chrome and Safari are able to evenly space out the li items based on the content but in IE it doesn't. Does anyone know of any quick fixes or point me in the right direction? I'm trying to avoid JS to set the widths and am trying to work out a CSS solution. Has anyone had this issue with the navbar in bootstrap?

**Navigation displaying correctly on firefox, chrome, safari**

[image: Navigation displaying correctly on firefox, chrome, safari]

**Navigation not evenly spacing out menu items on IE11, IE10, IE9 or IE8**

[image: Navigation not evenly spacing out menu items on IE11, IE10, IE9 or IE8]

I've put an example of JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/bGHL4/20/

```
<ul id="navPrimary" class="nav nav-justified">
                        <li id="navMenus"><a href="/menus/">Menus</a></li>
                        <li id="navOffers"><a href="/offers/">Offers</a></li>
                        <li id="navGallery"><a href="/gallery/">Gallery</a></li>
                        <li id="navBenefitGiftCards"><a href="/benefit-gift-card/">Benefit Cards</a></li>
                        <li id="navReservations"><a href="/reservations/">Reservations</a></li>
                        <li id="navContact"><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
                        <li class="last" id="navEvents"><a href="/events/">Events</a></li>
                    </ul>
```

On IE the Benefit Cards item has different space between that and gallery and reservations. However on all the other major browsers the spacing between all navigation items is consistent.

thanks

Comment: Can you throw some code up in your ticket or on jsfiddle so we can actually see what you're doing...

Comment: Tim, I've added a jsfiddle example.

Comment: Add this in your <head> and try `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" /> ` , For IE . This enables the IE browser to render elements in the highest mode possible.

Comment: Yeah I already have this tag in the html head but hasn't made a difference.